# Not able to import Kendo TimePicker component for Angular 2+

Tags: angular, npm, timepicker, kendo-ui-angular2

According to the KendoUI newsletter which I received through email this Wednesday(9/13/2017) New TimePicker  has been released. I am trying to import TimePicker component in my project but I am not able to do so. According to the API we are at Version 1.2.0 for kendo-angular-dateinputs which should contain TimePickerModule. I tried doing npm install by specifying that version (1.2.0) and I get below error message.

> fetchPackageMetaData  error for
>   @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs@^1.2.0 { Error: No compatible
>   version found: @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs@^1.0.6
> 37 silly
>   fetchPackageMetaData Valid install targets:
> 37 silly
>   fetchPackageMetaData 1.0.5, 1.0.5-dev.201706261326, 1.0.4,
>   1.0.4-dev.201706150809, 1.0.4-dev.201706131239, 1.0.3, 1.0.3-dev.201706051028, 1.0.2, 1.0.2-dev.201705311506, 1.0.2-dev.201705261318, 1.0.2-dev.201705240946, 1.0.2-dev.201705240940, 1.0.2-dev.201705221449, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.9.0, 0.8.3, 0.8.2, 0.8.1, 0.8.0, 0.7.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.3, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.7, 0.3.6, 0.3.5, 0.3.4, 0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.0, 0.1.0

In package json I added dependency as  "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^1.2.0". I am only able to get the latest version of 1.0.5 and when I add timepicker tags with that in my html then I get error messages saying:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   'kendo-timepicker' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'kendo-timepicker' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'kendo-timepicker' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
>    [ERROR ->]

Can anyone check to see if V1.2.0 is indeed actually available for people ?

Also copying the package json

```
    {
  "name": "test-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed I couldn't get any new updates via NPM, however I recently found the following on the NPM Packages page at http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/npm#kendo-ui-professional

> Important
>
> The Progress NPM registry was retired in favor of npmjs.com. To start using the default registry, remove the two lines which contain registry.npm.telerik.com from your .npmrc file.

To fix this up I removed the following line out of the ~/.npmrc file

`@progress:registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/`

After that all new packages are available

Comment: Thats crazy. Omg @cseils. I did what you said. I went to Users folder. Picked me and edited the .npmrc file to take out the syntax you said. After that I ran npm install and it installed the latest package !

Answer (score 1):

I setted dependencie in package.json to `"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^1.0.5"`, and installed version is `@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns    1.2.0`, so that is ok.

You can install version checker:

```
npm install -g version-check
```

then run command to see what version you have:

```
version-check
```

Did you import module in your root module?

```
import { TimePickerModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [HomeComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ButtonsModule,
        TimePickerModule
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

in html:

```
<kendo-timepicker 
    [format]="'HH:mm'" 
    name="workingTimeFrom" 
    [(ngModel)]="workingDay.startTime"
    (valueChange)="updateStartTime(i,$event)">
</kendo-timepicker>
```

Comment: Yes I did import TimePickerModule in the app module file. My problem is it is not letting me install greater than 1.05 version.